# How to use variable instead of xpath value in Selenium ...find_element(By.XPATH, "xpath")

Tags: python, variables, xpath, selenium4

Is there a way to use variable instead of string value for the xpath?

I am using:
`driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "xpath-value-string")`

But I need to replace the string (the xpath value) and use variable instead like this:
`my_xpath = "xpath-value-string"` 
`driver.find_element(By.XPATH, my_xpath)`
The goal is to pull various xpath values from the list and use them in for loop dynamically inserted as the xpath values.
I have found some advices of using .format; str(); f"{my_xpath} etc. to insert the values but nothing was working.
I am pyhton beginner. So maybe I am taking it wrong and it must be a string as the attribute not variable. Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
xpaths = ['xpath_example_1', 'xpath_example_2']
for xpath in xpaths:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)
```